How do you add App/Program Icons to Desktop 24.10
If I right click on any app icon there is no option "add to desktop"
I can pin them to the dock

Hmmm. Unable to duplicate the problem: When I open an application in a stock 24.10 install that is not on the dock, and then right-click on the icon that appears in the dock, A "Pin to dock" option is indeed there. And it works.

Are you running the stock Ubuntu distribution with gnome?

Do you work? https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2023/04/add-app-shortcut-desktop-ubuntu/

Thanks...was able to "add to desktop" thru the extension manager.
